# Spring jpa - объект не передается под управление EntityManager

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-jpa

Пытаюсь отдать объект под управление EntityManager, сделав em.persist(provider), но получаю ошибку

> No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread
>   - cannot reliably process 'persist' call

Конфигурация приложения:

```
package hello.config;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import hello.model.Item;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DbConfig {

    @Bean
    public Item getItem() {
        return new Item();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        hikariDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        hikariDataSource.setUsername("root");
        hikariDataSource.setPassword("123123");
        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/warehouse");
        return hikariDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan("hello");

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

Модель

```
package hello.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "providers")
public class Provider {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "items_providers",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name = "provider_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name = "item_id")})
    private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();

}
```

Dao для модели

```
package hello.dao.impl;

import hello.dao.ProviderDAO;
import hello.model.Provider;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class ProviderDaoImpl implements ProviderDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;


    @Override
    public List<Provider> findAll() {
        return em.createQuery("from Provider i").getResultList();
    }


}
```

Запуск приложения и контроллер - одновременно

```
package hello;

import hello.dao.ItemDao;
import hello.dao.ProviderDAO;
import hello.model.Item;
import hello.model.Provider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
public class AppMain {

    @Autowired
    private ProviderDAO providerDAO;

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    @Transactional
    String home() {

        List<Provider> providers = providerDAO.findAll();

        Provider provider = new Provider();
        provider.setName("Maksat");
        provider.setId(11L);

        em.persist(provider);

        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(AppMain.class, args);
    }
}
```

Метод `providerDAO.findAll()` выполняется успешно

Comment: Уберите "provider.setId()"